# How to show my React app to the others from GitLab?

Tags: reactjs, gitlab

Hi everybody im actually working for a company and they are asking me to **show them my React Website** while im working on it. They have a website that is **connected to our GitLab Project** and **if i type http.websitename/folderOnGitLab it actually comes out whats inside the folder** but with react it shows the code , not the website , because the only way i know how to open react app is by "*npm run start*" from local, i dont really know how to "***append my app in that website from GitLab***" . I have already pushed all my React App but i dont really know how to make that visible to everyone as a website not only as a code. The website is a website they host so is always online and is connected to the project as i said. So i kinda have all the material but dont know how to make that work. For example i have pushed Test.txt and if i type website/Test.txt it shows the inside of it , so the website works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your app was set up, but probably you need to run `npm run build`, which will package up your app to be used on a production website.

This will be in the `/build` folder, the contents of which can be hosted online.

I'm not sure how you've managed to get that folder working on that website, it definitely isn't best practice to have all the code hosted online like that, but for a temporary solution you can just go to http.websitename/folderOnGitLab/build and it will probably work.

In the future you want to copy just the contents of the /build folder to be visible on http.websitename/folderOnGitLab.

Edit: The /build folder will be excluded from git, don't put that on GitLab, just the other source files, as you can re-generate it any time by running `np run build`

Comment: So Actually i can just delete all my app and use the build one? because i did npm build and it creates all the app inside the build folder.And now i have inside my project 2 times the same things one isnide the build forlder one just isnide the main folder so i dont know now how to push it because i would push 2 times the same stuff should i just move the build folder on hes own one? Btw thx for your comment im trying and i ll let you know.

Comment: Ok i ran npm build but the build folder is not white but like with low opacity and when i commit it  says nothing to commit like i cannot push the build folder.

Comment: So the stuff outside the build folder is the source-code, and should be on GitLab.

The build folder should be the bit you put up on the website, but not on gitlab. It is deliberately excluded from being able to be put on gitlab, by gitignore.

Comment: ok thx got it but still i dont understand how to append the build to a website or to gitlab , because i have a website that they own where is connected to our gitlab but idk how to put that build. I did the command of deploy and the console dont show errors the problem is that the way i append the link i think is incorrect i dont know how to do it and where to set it.

Comment: That is a question for your webmaster or deploys team.

Comment: You could zip up the build file, and email that to the person who runs your website. The linking with the gitlab could work, but they'd have to run npm build on their deployment service, and host the build fe

Comment: I ll tell them today and let you know

Comment: Ok i added the build to GitLab and it shows now React App but is all white do i have to add something a path?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using heroku. Once you push to heroku, it deploys your code and provides a url which you can share. It's free.

https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration

Comment: does not let me use heroku , when i type the command it says i have not permision because <script> is disebled and it ask to enable.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using gitlab pipelines?

If yes, you can configure [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) in one of your jobs.

If someone wants to see your work, this person just need to play the job that have the ngrok tool and it will receive a custom link with the application.

To stop the app, you just need to click in the cancel button

Comment: i like this idea can you just tell me how can i setup this on gitLab? i saw how it works indipentently and i downloaded it but dont know exactly how to set up this on GitLab Pipeline